# Silica gel reheating (orange)

Tags: color, gel

I am a non-chemist looking for some advice! I am an archaeologist and am currently using moisture-indicating silica gel (orange) to dry out some metal finds from our excavations. I have reheated silica gel before but I am looking for a refresher as it is many years I've done it!

I intend to heat a small amount at a high temperature (can anyone advise what temperature?) in an oven that is used solely for this purpose. How long do I need to heat it for? If I heat it for longer, is it likely to retain its colour for longer?

Additionally, how well ventilated does the space I am in need to be? I intend to wear gloves and a light-weight mask.

Comment: Consult [Preparing Silica Gel for Contained Storage of Metal Objects – Canadian Conservation Institute (CCI) Notes 9/14](https://www.canada.ca/en/conservation-institute/services/conservation-preservation-publications/canadian-conservation-institute-notes/prep-silica-gel.html)

Comment: @Poutnik, *perfect* answer!